# how to mock a nested private interface?

Tags: jmockit

I took a look at `Deencapsulation` but found no way to mock a nested private interface. That is, given:

```
class Foo {
    private static interface Bar {};
}
```

How can I mock `Bar`?

Comment: If it's private, that suggests your tests shouldn't even be aware of it... it's very hard to suggest how to proceed without more context though.

Comment: very true. My tests, however, are intended to produce coverage. Hence, they are rather obfuscated. I am  not going after design-oriented alternatives here. I would consider it a [characterization test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test) ...

Comment: "My tests, however, are intended to produce coverage." That's rarely a useful goal in itself, IMO. Surely you only need to characterize how it behaves with regards to input/output...